# How can I draw two impulses plot in gnuplot using a rowstacked option?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to plot an impulses plot and this is my current script:

```
set terminal pngcairo transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 500, 350 
set output 'test.png'
set key bmargin left horizontal Right noreverse enhanced autotitles box linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
plot 'example.csv' using 2:xtic(1) title col with impulses lw 15, \
                '' using 3:xtic(1) title col with impulses lw 15, \
                '' using 4:xtic(1) title col with impulses lw 15
```

The data input is:

```
var basis out1 out2
param1 0.1 0.3 0.5 
param2 -0.1 0.4 -0.6 
param3 0.4 0.6 0.8 
param4 -0.4 -0.5 -0.6 
param -0.1 0.0 0.1
```

And this is the current output:

gnuplot example.gnu

[image]

So I was trying to stack the bars in a row position similar to an option for histograms (`set style histogram rowstacked`), but I was unsuccessful.

The example for what I want with histograms would be:

[image]

Is there something similar for impulses plot?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a rowstacked histogram, why don't you simply use one? With

```
set style data histogram
```

you set `histogram` as global plotting style for all plots, and with

```
set style histogram rowstacked clustered
```

you get clustering of all values in a row. A full example script (with some visual enhancements) is:

```
reset
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked clustered gap 2
set boxwidth 0.9 relative
set style fill solid noborder
set key auto columnheader tmargin horizontal Right
set xzeroaxis
plot for [i=2:4] 'example.csv' u i:xtic(1)
```

with the output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need an options similar to rowstacked, but what I need is that the bars of column (basis, out1, and out2) show up side by side, similar to the Example. In your answer, you used the option `set xzeroaxis` for histograms, and this will be very helpful for what I need. Thanks again.

Comment: Then you must plot a `rowstacked clustered` histogram, see my update.